# What does $o(1)$ stand for here?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's assume that $ k= o(\sqrt n ) $

In this case,
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\ln(1-\frac{i}{n}) \sim  \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (- \frac{i}{n})= -\frac {1}{n} \frac{(k-1)k}{2}=o(1)
$$

Then, 
$$ e^{o(1)} \sim 1 \quad as \quad n \to \infty
$$

Here I dont understand how this similarities/approximations$\quad(\sim) \quad $are made and also how the equations at third line end up to be $o(1)$

But most importantly I dont know what do we mean by $o(1)$

Any definition could you give me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$o(1)$ is **any** function which satisfies a particular property:  It satisfies that $o(1)/1$ goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.  In other words, $o(1)$ is just a general name for any expression $f(n)$ which satisfies $f(n)/1 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Similarly, if I said an expression $g(n)$ is $o(n^{2})$, it means $g(n)/n^{2} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  The interpretation here is that $n^{2}$ grows much faster than $g(n)$ as $n \to \infty$.  How fast?  Fast enough that the ratio $g(n)/n^{2}$ tends to $0$.

So, going back to the original example, if $f(n)$ is $o(1)$, that means $1$ grows much faster than $f(n)$ in the sense that $f(n)/1$ tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.  But since $f(n)/1 = f(n)$, that means $f(n)$ tends to $0$.  So, $o(1)$ is notation for any function which tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

To follow up with your question about $e^{o(1)} \sim 1$ as $n \to \infty$, what is meant here is this:  since $o(1)$ is a function of $n$ which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, that means for large enough $n$, the function $o(1)$ is as small as you want (since it keeps tending to $0$).  Ok, but then the function $e^{x}$ is **continuous** everywhere, so it's continuous at $0$.  That means if $x$ is really close to $0$, then $e^{x}$ is really close to $e^{0} = 1$.

Now, remember that for large enough $n$, $o(1)$ is really close to $0$.  That means $e^{o(1)}$ is really close to $1$, for large enough $n$ (by the continuity of $e^{x}$ at $x = 0$).  So, $e^{o(1)} \sim 1$ as $n \to \infty$ should be interpreted by you as "for large enough $n$, $e^{o(1)}$ is really close to $1$", and we know this is true since $e^{x}$ is continuous at $x = 0$, and $o(1)$ is close to $0$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: What about this one:  $$\ln (1-x)= -x+O(x^2) $$  I know that $$\sum \frac{x^n}{n}=-\ln (1-x) $$ So, what does $O(x^2) $ have meaning here?  @user46944

Comment: Typically when you write little o or Big O notation, you have a sort of limit notation beside it, like $f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to 0$, or something like that.  So, for example, $f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to a$ means for some $\delta>0$ and constant $C>0$, $|x - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)| \leq C|g(x)|$.  In other words, for all $x$ near $a$, the magnitude of $f$ is bounded by the magnitude of $g$ (up to constant multiples of $g$). 
 This document has the definition on the first page: web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf

Comment: Let's take a look at your specific example from the comments.  We have $\ln(1-x) = -x + O(x^{2})$. I think it should actually be written as $\ln(1-x) = -x + O(x^{2})$ as $x \to 0$.  How did they get this?  According to the first few pages of the document linked at the end of this comment, $\ln(1-x)$ can be written as $T_{n}(x) + R_{n}(x)$, where $T_{n}$ is the $n$-th degree Taylor polynomial of $\ln(1-x)$, and $R_{n}(x)$ is the remainder term.  On page $3$, a bound for the remainder term is established:

Comment: $|R_{n}(x)| \leq \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n + 1)!}$ near $x = 0$.  In particular, take $n = 1$.  Then $T_{1}(x) = -x$, and so we know by the document that $\ln(1-x) = T_{1}(x)  + R_{1}(x) = -x + R_{1}(x)$, and we know for $x$ near $0$, $|R_{1}(x)| \leq \frac{|x|^{2}}{2} = C|x|^{2}$.  This is the precise definition of $R_{1}(x)$ being $O(x^{2})$.  So, we write $O(x^{2})$ (as $x \to 0$) in place of $R_{1}(x)$ to signify that the function $R_{1}(x)$ is bounded in magnitude by a constant times the magnitude of $x^{2}$, i.e.,  the "size" of $R_{1}(x)$ is controlled by the size of $C x^{2}$.

Comment: Here is the document I was referencing in the previous two comments: http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Early%20Transcendentals/upfiles/Formulas4RemainderTaylorSeries5ET.pdf

Answer (score 2):

From the Taylor development

$$\ln\left(1-\frac in\right)\sim-\frac in,$$ and this explains the first similarity.

Then as $k=o(\sqrt n)$, mechanically $\dfrac{k^2}n=o(1)$.

Finally, the antilogarithm of $0$ is $1$.

Comment: What is a Taylor development and how we use it?

Comment: @LeylaAlkan What is your level ??

Comment: Undergraduate..

Comment: I just saw the note that says $$ as \quad x\to 0, \ln (1−x) \sim -x $$, I guess the above expression is made by this simple approximation

Comment: @LeylaAlkan: differentiable functions can be well approximated by polynomials for small values of the argument. In particular, a linear approximation $f(x)\approx a+bx$ holds. Check the graph of $\ln(1-x)$ for small $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$o(1)$ means that the expression tends towards $0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$